# Большие отсупы в UINavigationBar в IOS7

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, iphone, ios7

В IOS7  были увеличены отступы от карев екрана к кнопкам в UINavigationBar
в чем суть проблемы лучше посмотреть

Так выглядит в IOS6

[image]

А вот так в IOS7

[image]

Как видно на картинке изза малого пространства кнопи налазят друг на друга

Какие есть варианты решения кроме как уменьшить размер кнопок или удалить сами кнопки

UPD:
нашел решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861201/uibarbuttonitem-with-custom-view-not-properly-aligned-on-ios-7-when-used-as-left

Comment: Поиграйтесь с `UIEdgeInsets`

Comment: в UINavigationBar свойства с таким типом вроде нет, а играться с UIViewController-от смысла нет - не помогает

Comment: У вас там кастомные кнопки лежат, у них есть такое свойство, играйтесь с ними

Comment: @Svyatoslavik, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа, чтобы Вы могли получить заслуженную репутацию. Если Вы не успеете сделать это до 09.08, я оформлю ответ в качестве общего (за него не начисляется репутация) - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения необходимо унаслдеваоть класс UIButton; и переопределить в нем метод alignmentRectInsets:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets {
    UIEdgeInsets insets;
    if (IF_ITS_A_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9.0f, 0, 0);
    } 
    else { // IF_ITS_A_RIGHT_BUTTON
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 9.0f);
    }
    return insets;
}
```